# Was Mary sleeping in your class yesterday?

Tags: grammar

A teacher asked his colleague:

1. Was Mary sleeping in your class yesterday? She was sleeping in my class.
2. Did Mary sleep in your class yesterday? She slept in my class.

Why is the first better than the second? We are talking about the past (yesterday), and we aren't talking about an ongoing action at a specific point of time. Isn't it better to use the past simple?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you ***are*** talking about an ongoing action at a specific point in time.  Sleeping is an ongoing action.

Comment: Arguably the "best" version might be *Was Mary **asleep...?***

Comment: Neither is *better*. It's entirely a matter of context, style, and personal opinion.

Comment: 'Did John sleep in your shed yesterday?' Is enquiring about a location primarily. 'Did Mary sleep in your class yesterday? She slept in my class' sounds at best awkward and is _worse_ than some other options. I'd disagree with FF also; 'Did Mary fall asleep in your class yesterday!?' ...'Yes, she did!' is most idiomatic IMHO.